# Removing action added from constructor

Tags: hooks

Is there a way to remove action from theme that are added via plugin's class inside the constructor?
Example:

```
class WP_Travel_Engine_Enquiry_Form_Shortcodes
{

    function __construct()
    {
        add_action('wp_travel_engine_enquiry_form', array( $this, 'wpte_enquiry_form' ));
    }
}
new WP_Travel_Engine_Enquiry_Form_Shortcodes;
```

So can I remove the action `wpte_enquiry_form` from `wp_travel_engine_enquiry_form` via theme? I am unable to do so as the action is added instantly when the object is created. Is there a way possible?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that class works as a singleton and has a getInstance() method (or similar) to retrieve the instance, you can remove the action pretty much the same way it was added:

```
remove_action('wp_travel_engine_enquiry_form', array( $instance, 'wpte_enquiry_form' ));
```

Edit: I've looked into this some more, and you find the necessary information by looking into `$wp_filters` (global variable, so use `global $wp_filters;` before working with it in a function).

```
add_action("init", function() {
    global $wp_filter;
    foreach($wp_filter["wp_travel_engine_enquiry_form"][10] as $id => $filter) {
    if(is_array($filter["function"]) && && count($filter["function"]) == 2 &&
        get_class($filter["function"][0]) == "WP_Travel_Engine_Enquiry_Form_Shortcodes" &&
        $filter["function"][1] == "wpte_enquiry_form") {
            remove_action("wp_travel_engine_enquiry_form", $id);
        }
    }
}, 99);
```

This code is looking at the filters/actions (they are the same thing, but filters are generally expected to return something; internally, add_action is an alias for add_filter) for the `wp_travel_engine_enquiry_form` hook. 10 is the default priority, but you could easily iterate of the other priorities as well.

It then looks at each individual filter whether it is a [callable](http://php.net/manual/language.types.callable.php) with an object and a method, and whether that object is of the right type and the right method we want to remove. As the ID is known then, `remove_action` is used to manipulate `$wp_filter`.

It's not the cleanest of ways, but drastic times call for drastic measures.

Comment: As you can see, no object is defined in the plugin class. So, how can I use remove action in the theme to remove that action. Is there any other way around? Please help!

Comment: @saurav.rox I've edited my answer and added a way to solve this.

Comment: Great! Could still use it today - quite low level ugly workaround, but only possible way sometimes :)