# How to remove an action that is added inside a class

Tags: actions

Here is the code in short that is coming from a plugin:

```
class Post_Views_Counter_Columns {
     public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'wp', array( $this, 'admin_bar_maybe_add_style' ) );
    }
}
```

I want to remove this `admin_bar_maybe_add_style` function. I am trying with following code in my **child theme's functions.php**

```
remove_action( 'wp', array( 'Post_Views_Counter_Columns', 'admin_bar_maybe_add_style' ) );
```

It's not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is that class coming from a plugin, or where does it inherit from?

Comment: @WPTricksDK it's coming from a plugin. Sorry I didn't mention that.

Comment: Please take a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639146/wordpress-remove-action-defined-within-plugin-class

Don't know if you've tried this already or not - but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Where/how is `Post_Views_Counter_Columns` instantiated?

Comment: I hate this type of classes, in order to remove the action you need to create a instance of that class, when creating an instance the action is called... so anoying. See [Removing action added from constructor](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/291180/removing-action-added-from-constructor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand any of it but it seems to work just fine. Thank you @Buttered_Toast for mentioning the useful thread.

```
add_action("init", function() {
    global $wp_filter;
    foreach($wp_filter["wp"][10] as $id => $filter) {
    if(is_array($filter["function"]) && count($filter["function"]) == 2 &&
        get_class($filter["function"][0]) == "Post_Views_Counter_Columns" &&
        $filter["function"][1] == "admin_bar_maybe_add_style") {
            remove_action("wp", $id);
        }
    }
}, 99);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also wrote my own little funciton, very similar to the one mentioned above. Here it is, it considers all priorities of a given hook or only one if you enter a numeric priority.

You can define your own check function.

```
    function dynamically_remove_hooks($hook, $priorities, $callback_check_function)
{
    global $wp_filter;
    if(!isset($wp_filter[$hook]))
        return;

    if(is_numeric($priorities))
        $priorities = array((int)$priorities);
    elseif(!$priorities && isset($wp_filter[$hook]->callbacks) && is_array($wp_filter[$hook]->callbacks))
        $priorities = array_keys($wp_filter[$hook]->callbacks);

    foreach($priorities as $priority)
    {
        if(isset($wp_filter[$hook]->callbacks[$priority]))
        {
            foreach ($wp_filter[$hook]->callbacks[$priority] as $identifier => $callback) {
                if ($callback_check_function( $callback )) {
                    unset( $wp_filter[$hook]->callbacks[$priority][$identifier] );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You call it like this, if e.g. you would like to remove all hooks created by the CLASS Post_Views_Counter_Columns for the hook name `wp`:

```
dynamically_remove_hooks('wp', false, function($callback) {
    return isset($callback['function'][0]) && get_class($callback['function'][0]) == 'Post_Views_Counter_Columns ';
});
```

You can define all sorts of callback check functions to have various different logics :)