# How to remove a hook written with $this?

Tags: plugins, hooks

I'm trying to remove an action defined in the theme, but I'm getting an error. I guess because of the $this definition. What exactly should I do for this?

Hook position :
**/themes/theme/vendors/dokan.php**
Hook:

```
add_action( 'dokan_new_product_after_product_tags', array( $this, 'add_product_brand_field' ) );
```

**My code in function.php:**

```
function remove_brand_1234(){
(Line:1206) remove_action( 'dokan_new_product_after_product_tags', array( $this, 'add_product_brand_field' ) );
}
add_action('init', 'remove_brand_1234 ', 10);
```

**The error I got:**
Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in wp-content/themes/theme-child/functions.php:1206

Class:

```
<?php
class X_Dokan {

    function __construct() {
        if ( ! class_exists( 'WeDevs_Dokan' ) ) {
            return;
        }
        // Settings

        add_action( 'dokan_new_product_after_product_tags', array( $this, 'add_product_brand_field' ) );

    }
```

Note: As far as I can see $this points to a construct. However, I have no clue how to define it. I searched but couldn't find a general result.

Comment: [This article](https://inpsyde.com/en/remove-wordpress-hooks/) addresses the issue. I don't have time right now to test it / write up a complete answer though

Comment: The "great" action inside a construct, always great fun. see [How to remove an action that is added inside a class](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/392931/how-to-remove-an-action-that-is-added-inside-a-class#comment572755_392931), the OP answer should work for you as well, just update it accordingly to your needs

Comment: You need a reference to the object `$this` refers to. How that is made available, or even if it's made available, is up to the Dokan theme. Once you get a reference to that object you can use it instead of `$this` ( `$this` always refers to yourself, aka the current object the code is in, if you are outside of an object it is meaningless and has no value ). I strongly recommend looking up callables on php.net

Answer (score 0):

$this refers to the class "WeDevs_Dokan" most likely.

Replace:

```
remove_action( 'dokan_new_product_after_product_tags', array( $this, 'add_product_brand_field' ) );
```

With:

```
remove_action( 'dokan_new_product_after_product_tags', array( 'WeDevs_Dokan', 'add_product_brand_field' ) );
```

And see if that works. Sometimes classes are namespaced, so check the file to see if that's the case and include that before the WeDev_Dokan string.

Comment: I tried this but wasn't sure. Actually I solved the problem. But not with this. Because I realized that what I want to remove is not this hook. Thank you for your answer. If I see any effect, I will write. Maybe someone else will need it.

Comment: This will only work if it's a static function

Comment: $this refer to a specific object not a class, knowing the class is not enough at all