# How to unset a function from a action inside a class, that is called in another class

Tags: php, functions

I need to unset a function from an action, but the function is set to an action inside a class, and this class is just called from another class. How can I do this?

I want to unset the `function handle_product_add()`

The first class where the function is set in the class:

```php
class Products {

    public static $errors;
    public static $product_cat;
    public static $post_content;

    /**
     *  Load autometially when class initiate
     *
     *  @since 2.4
     *
     *  @uses actions
     *  @uses filters
     */
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'dokan_render_product_listing_template', array( $this, 'render_product_listing_template' ), 11 );
        add_action( 'template_redirect', array( $this, 'handle_product_add' ), 11 );
    }
    public function handle_product_add() {

        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( ! dokan_is_user_seller( get_current_user_id() ) ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( ! isset( $_POST['dokan_add_new_product_nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( sanitize_key( $_POST['dokan_add_new_product_nonce'] ), 'dokan_add_new_product' )  ) {
            return;
        }

        $postdata = wp_unslash( $_POST );

        $errors             = array();
        self::$product_cat  = -1;
        self::$post_content = __( 'Details of your product ...', 'dokan-lite' );

        if ( isset( $postdata['add_product'] ) ) {
            $post_title     = sanitize_text_field( $postdata['post_title'] );
            $post_content   = wp_kses_post( $postdata['post_content'] );
            $post_excerpt   = wp_kses_post( $postdata['post_excerpt'] );
            $featured_image = absint( sanitize_text_field( $postdata['feat_image_id'] ) );

            if ( empty( $post_title ) ) {
                $errors[] = __( 'Please enter product title', 'dokan-lite' );
            }

            /*if ( dokan_get_option( 'product_category_style', 'dokan_selling', 'single' ) == 'single' ) {
                $product_cat = intval( $postdata['product_cat'] );

                if ( $product_cat < 0 ) {
                    $errors[] = __( 'Please select a category', 'dokan-lite' );
                }

            } else {
                if ( ! isset( $postdata['product_cat'] ) && empty( $postdata['product_cat'] ) ) {
                    $errors[] = __( 'Please select AT LEAST ONE category', 'dokan-lite' );
                }
            }*/

            self::$errors = apply_filters( 'dokan_can_add_product', $errors );

            if ( ! self::$errors ) {
                $product_status = dokan_get_new_post_status();
                $post_data = apply_filters( 'dokan_insert_product_post_data', array(
                    'post_type'    => 'product',
                    'post_status'  => $product_status,
                    'post_title'   => $post_title,
                    'post_content' => $post_content,
                    'post_excerpt' => $post_excerpt,
                ) );

                $product_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data );

                if ( $product_id ) {
                    /** set images **/
                    if ( $featured_image ) {
                        set_post_thumbnail( $product_id, $featured_image );
                    }

                    if ( isset( $postdata['product_tag'] ) && ! empty( $postdata['product_tag'] ) ) {
                        $tags_ids = array_map( 'absint', (array) $postdata['product_tag'] );
                        wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, $tags_ids, 'product_tag' );
                    }

                    /** set product category * */
                    if ( dokan_get_option( 'product_category_style', 'dokan_selling', 'single' ) == 'single' ) {
                        wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, (int) $postdata['product_cat'], 'product_cat' );
                    } else {
                        if ( isset( $postdata['product_cat'] ) && ! empty( $postdata['product_cat'] ) ) {
                            $cat_ids = array_map( 'absint', (array) $postdata['product_cat'] );
                            wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, $cat_ids, 'product_cat' );
                        }
                    }

                    /** Set Product type, default is simple */
                    $product_type = empty( $postdata['product_type'] ) ? 'simple' : $postdata['product_type'];
                    wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, $product_type, 'product_type' );

                    // Gallery Images
                    if ( ! empty( $postdata['product_image_gallery'] ) ) {
                        $attachment_ids = array_filter( explode( ',', wc_clean( $postdata['product_image_gallery'] ) ) );
                        update_post_meta( $product_id, '_product_image_gallery', implode( ',', $attachment_ids ) );
                    }

                    if ( isset( $postdata['_regular_price'] ) ) {
                        update_post_meta( $product_id, '_regular_price', ( $postdata['_regular_price'] === '' ) ? '' : wc_format_decimal( $postdata['_regular_price'] ) );
                    }

                    if ( isset( $postdata['_sale_price'] ) ) {
                        update_post_meta( $product_id, '_sale_price', ( $postdata['_sale_price'] === '' ? '' : wc_format_decimal( $postdata['_sale_price'] ) ) );
                        $date_from = isset( $postdata['_sale_price_dates_from'] ) ? wc_clean( $postdata['_sale_price_dates_from'] ) : '';
                        $date_to   = isset( $postdata['_sale_price_dates_to'] ) ? wc_clean( $postdata['_sale_price_dates_to'] ) : '';

                        // Dates
                        if ( $date_from ) {
                            update_post_meta( $product_id, '_sale_price_dates_from', strtotime( $date_from ) );
                        } else {
                            update_post_meta( $product_id, '_sale_price_dates_from', '' );
                        }

                        if ( $date_to ) {
                            update_post_meta( $product_id, '_sale_price_dates_to', strtotime( '+23 hours', strtotime( $date_to ) ) );
                        } else {
                            update_post_meta( $product_id, '_sale_price_dates_to', '' );
                        }

                        if ( $date_to && ! $date_from ) {
                            update_post_meta( $product_id, '_sale_price_dates_from', strtotime( 'NOW', current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) );
                        }

                        if ( '' !== $postdata['_sale_price'] && '' == $date_to && '' == $date_from ) {
                            update_post_meta( $product_id, '_price', wc_format_decimal( $postdata['_sale_price'] ) );
                        } else {
                            update_post_meta( $product_id, '_price', ( $postdata['_regular_price'] === '' ) ? '' : wc_format_decimal( $postdata['_regular_price'] ) );
                        }
                        // Update price if on sale
                        if ( '' !== $postdata['_sale_price'] && $date_from && strtotime( $date_from ) < strtotime( 'NOW', current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) ) {
                            update_post_meta( $product_id, '_price', wc_format_decimal( $postdata['_sale_price'] ) );
                        }
                    }

                    update_post_meta( $product_id, '_visibility', 'visible' );
                    update_post_meta( $product_id, '_stock_status', 'instock' );

                    do_action( 'dokan_new_product_added', $product_id, $postdata );

                    if ( current_user_can( 'dokan_edit_product' ) ) {
                        $redirect = dokan_edit_product_url( $product_id );
                    } else {
                        $redirect = dokan_get_navigation_url( 'products' );
                    }

                    if ( 'create_and_add_new' === $postdata['add_product'] ) {
                        $redirect = add_query_arg( array( 'created_product' => $product_id ), dokan_get_navigation_url( 'new-product' ) );
                    }

                    wp_redirect( apply_filters( 'dokan_add_new_product_redirect', $redirect, $product_id ) );
                    exit;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The other class where the first class is called is this:

```php
<?php

namespace WeDevs\Dokan\Dashboard\Templates;

use WeDevs\Dokan\Dashboard\Templates\Dashboard;
use WeDevs\Dokan\Dashboard\Templates\Main;
use WeDevs\Dokan\Dashboard\Templates\Orders;
use WeDevs\Dokan\Dashboard\Templates\Products;
use WeDevs\Dokan\Dashboard\Templates\Settings;
use WeDevs\Dokan\Dashboard\Templates\Withdraw;
use WeDevs\Dokan\Traits\ChainableContainer;

class Manager {

    use ChainableContainer;

    /**
     * Class constructor
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->container['main']      = new Main();
        $this->container['dashboard'] = new Dashboard();
        $this->container['products']  = new Products();
        $this->container['orders']    = new Orders();
        $this->container['settings']  = new Settings();
        $this->container['withdraw']  = new Withdraw();
    }
}
```

I saw a tutorial that says that I need to declare the var where the first class is set, and then unset the function from the action, but I don't have any var, just another class.

Comment: See [How to remove an action that is added inside a class](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/392931/how-to-remove-an-action-that-is-added-inside-a-class#comment572755_392931). OPs answer should work for you, just change it accordingly.

Comment: You need a PHP callable that matches aka `array( $obj, 'handle_product_add handle_product_add' )` where `$obj` is a reference to that very same object. You can't use `"Products"` as it is not a static class function. You will probably need help from Dokan support or other Dokan users to figure out how to get that value, if that value can be retrieved at all

Comment: A reference to the instance of `Products` you need is stored inside the Manager class, but where/how is that class instantiated?