# Using Remove Action Hook in Plugin

Tags: plugins, hooks

I'm trying to remove a hook using the remove action hook in a plugin I'm working on. However, the code I wrote in the function.php file (child theme) does not work.
If I directly comment the hook (related hook [here](https://i.ibb.co/Ydx6QRb/remove-t.png) ) the code works. I couldn't find what I'm doing wrong. I would be glad if you help.

My Code:

```
function remove_a_feature_for_seller(){
remove_action('dokan_settings_form_bottom', array(dokan_pro()->settings, 'render_biography_form'), 10, 2);

}
add_action('init', 'remove_a_feature_for_seller');
```

Comment: Because this action is part of a constructor it would be best to remove it completly, see [How to remove an action that is added inside a class](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/392931/how-to-remove-an-action-that-is-added-inside-a-class), [Removing action added from constructor](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/291180/removing-action-added-from-constructor)

Comment: I tried this way but it didn't work. I also got a warning like get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given in.